# Rest operator - dynamically remove elements to get rest

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's an option to acheive effect as below

```
const x = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4,
  e:5
}

const y = ['a', 'b'];
```

To get only `c,d,e` I can easily go with rest operator:

```
const { a, b, ...rest} = x;
```

and `rest` contain 3 keys

The **code below is not working** - but is there a  way to do it somehow with rest operator?

```
const { ...y, ...rest} = x;
```

To have in `rest` those 3 keys
so if `i` would define

```
const y = ['a','b','c']
```

then I would have 2 keys in `rest`?

Comment: You can just iterate over the keys manually using `Object.keys()`. What is the goal here? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curried ES6 partial implementation of `_.omit` (and, for good measure, `_.pick`):

```js
const data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
const someKeys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
  
const pick = keys => o =>
  keys.reduce(
    (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: o[key] }),
    {}
  )
  
console.log(
  `pick [${someKeys}]:`,
  pick(someKeys)(data)
)
// -> { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
  
const omit = keys => o => 
  pick(Object.keys(o).filter(k => !(keys.includes(k))))(o)

console.log(
  `omit [${someKeys}]:`,
  omit(someKeys)(data)
)
// -> { d: 4, e: 5 }

const fromEntries = entries =>
  entries.reduce(
    (acc, [k, v]) => Object.assign(acc, { [k]: v }),
    {}
  )
  
console.log(
  'fromEntries:',
  fromEntries(Object.entries(data))
)
// -> { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 5 }
```

I rewrote `omit` and `pick` to be more efficient, and neither depends on `fromEntries` any more. I left `fromEntries` in, anyway, since it can be pretty useful (to turn the output of `Object.entries()` into an object). [`Object.fromEntries()` is a stage 3 proposal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries), so will hopefully be widely supported at some point, but this version may be useful in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not as elegant as you would want, but if you want to dynamically get the keys not in an array you can use:

```js
const x = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4,
  e:5
}

const y = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const rest = Object.keys(x).filter(key => y.indexOf(key) === -1);

console.log(rest);
```

Basically we get the keys for that object and filter those not present in the `y` array.

Answer (score 0):

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/), you can do the following:

**Updated answer**

```
const x = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4,
  e:5
}

const y = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const rest = _.omit(x,y)

console.log(rest);
```

**Original answer**

```
const x = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4,
  e:5
}

const y = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const rest = _.pick(x,_.difference(_.keys(x),y))

console.log(rest);
```

Code explained:

- `_.keys(x)` returns `['a','b','c','d','e']`
- `_.difference(['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','c'])` returns `['d','e']`
- `_.pick({a:1,b:2,c:3,d:4,e:5},['d','e'])` returns `{d:4,e:5}`

Comment: Wouldnt be easier to use _.omit here?

Answer (score 0):

ES6 lodash pick replacement:

```
const x = {
  a:1,
  b:2,
  c:3,
  d:4,
  e:5
}
const y = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const out = Object.assign({}, ...y.map(key => ({ [key]: x[key] })))
```

Comment: `out` contains a,b,c keys here - not d,e

Comment: This is a solution to extract first variables (something like rest spread on beginning ). Tex has added answer to capture both cases.